# How to open .rdb file using R

Tags: r

My question is quite simple, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. 
How do I open a .rdb file using R?

It is placed inside an R package.

Comment: What do you mean not working? What error message did you get?

Comment: I mean they do not exist. I am making up functions based on other functions I know that exist, like readRDS (which reads the metadata file) or read.csv (which reads a csv file).

Comment: Please see this post related to RDB files. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242431/what-are-rdx-and-rdb-files-for-r

Comment: Ok, then you should edit your question and explain what `rdb` files are.

Comment: @Sagar yes, I have seen this, but it does not tell me how to open the file.

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal - From what I read, it seems you cannot open those files in R. Just thought of sharing though. Good luck.

Comment: what package is this ? you can probably easily find the source code, no need to look at rdb files

Comment: The package is called Rsafd. I have actually found a function that might help opening the file. It is called lazyLoad. It is at the end of [this link](http://www.quantide.com/ramarro-chapter-06/). I still hav e to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem, so I am posting the answer here in case someone needs it in the future.

```
#### Importing data from .rdb file ####

setwd("path...\\Rsafd\\Rsafd\\data")  # Set working directory up to the file that contains
# your .rds and .rdb files.

readRDS("Rdata.rds")  # see metadata contained in .rds file

# lazyLoad is the function we use to open a .rdb file:
lazyLoad(filebase = "path...\\Rsafd\\Rsafd\\data\\Rdata", envir = parent.frame())
# for filebase, Rdata is the name of the .rdb file.
# envir is the environment on which the objects are loaded.
```

The result of using the lazyLoad function is that every database contained in the .rdb file shows up in your variable environment as a "promise". This means that the database will not be opened unless you want it to be.

The way to open it is the following:

```
find(HOWAREYOU)  # open the file named HOWAREYOU
head(HOWAREYOU)  # look at the first entries, just to make sure
```

Edit: readRDS is not part of the process to open the .rdb file, it is just to look at the metadata. The lazyLoad function indeed opens .rdb files.

Comment: Don't get it - .rds file != .rdb file?

Comment: @python_enthusiast, you've asked the question for .rdb files but your answer contains .rds

Comment: The .rds file I am just opening to see which data I have (see comment on the side). The lazyLoad(...) is opening the .rdb file.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a slightly more direct answer since I keep Googling to this Q&A when trying to examine .rdb objects inside an R package (in particular the `help/package.rdb` file) and not seeing the answer clearly enough.

R keeps the help `Rd` objects for the installed package `pkg` at `help/$pkg.{rdb,rdx}`.

We can load these `Rd` objects into environment `e` like so:

```
lazyLoad(
  file.path(system.file("help", package=pkg), pkg),
  envir = e
)
```

Note that we can't use `system.file("help", pkg, package=pkg)` because `system.file()` requires the file to exist or it returns `""`, and here we've truncated the `.rdb`/`.rdx` extension as required by `lazyLoad()`.

We can skip supplying `envir=e`, but the objects will be loaded into the global environment (assuming you're running this interactively) and I wanted my default answer to avoid polluting it.

See `?lazyLoad` for more.