# Search string against variable names of internal variables in an R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am writing an R package which has internal variables stored in pkg/R/sysdata.rda. In the package, I have a function `useVar(x)` that should recognise if the string `x` is a variable name in sysdata.rda and if so return the corresponding variable.

What is best way(s) to do this?

#### Using `:::` with strings

`pkg:::var` would help me but only if `var` can be specified as a string.

#### Listing internal variables

Another option would be to list the contents of sysdata.rda but I have not found a solution to this that feels right.

While [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927126/how-to-view-internal-variables-of-an-r-package-within-an-r-session) is related, the answers are directed at package *users* rather than at package *developers*. **Edit:** I am assuming that internal variables should be called differently from within a package since they are not supposed to be seen by users.

Comment: Why not have one of the internal variables be a character vector with all the other internal variable names? Then you can check `var %in% pkg:::internal_vars`

Comment: I believe what you're asking for in the question is `getFromNamespace`, e.g., `try(getFromNamespace(var, ns = "pkg"))`. That's not very different from the answer you link to--so it would be nice also if you would explain *why* the answer addressed at a package user is not working for you.

Comment: @Gregor I did think of this at some point, but since I will add to the variables in sysdata.rda with time, it felt a bit inelegant to me to have to also update ```pkg:::internal_vars``` each time.  Could be wrong.

Comment: @Gregor edited. I was unsure whether internal variables should be called differently from within a package since they are not supposed to be seen by users. Assuming that this isn't a worry, ```try(getFromNamespace(var, ns = "pkg"))``` does what I need. Thanks.