# how to view, open and save a .rdb file in RStudio

Tags: r

I am able to see every database in the .rdb file in the variable environment as a "promise" as per direction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184224/how-to-open-rdb-file-using-r). Now, I want to edit one of the file and save it. How can I do that? I am new in R.

Comment: Could you provide some more details?

Answer (score 0):

In a discussion on [r-pkg-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2020q2/005587.html), Ivan Krylov provided the following function ro read an RDB database:

```
# filename: the .rdb file
# offset, size: the pair of values from the .rdx
# type: 'gzip' if $compressed is TRUE, 'bzip2' for 2, 'xz' for 3
readRDB <- function(filename, offset, size, type = 'gzip') {
        f <- file(filename, 'rb')
        on.exit(close(f))
        seek(f, offset + 4)
        unserialize(memDecompress(readBin(f, 'raw', size - 4), type))
}
```

Therefore, you should be able to implement the reverse using a combination of `serialize`, `memCompress`, and `writeBin`.

Note that if the object changes size, you will also have to adjust the index file.