# rebuild R source package from installed version?

Tags: r, r-package

Suppose I have an R package installed on my system, but the source code (tarball etc.) is hard to retrieve.  I'd like to find the easiest way to reconstruct as much of the package as possible (R code, man pages, etc.; in this case there are no binaries/compiled code in the package), i.e. I'd like to reverse-engineer the source code of the package.

The installed version of an R package on my system has the following directories:

```
data  DESCRIPTION  help  html  INDEX  libs  LICENSE  Meta  NAMESPACE   R
```

For a package called `foo`, the `R` and `help` directories (which are of greatest interest) each contain files `foo.rdb`, `foo.rdx`; these are not particularly human-readable (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242431/what-are-rdx-and-rdb-files-for-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184224/how-to-open-rdb-file-using-r)).

Top priority is recovering the R code in source form; it would be nice to fully reverse-engineer and get `man` directory as well ...

Comment: Host a test package somewhere for us to play with?

Comment: But also: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69930661/12685768

Comment: close enough, I think ...